# Adding data(foreign keys) in database without using form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to add data to my model Item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    type_id = models.ForeignKey('Type')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User')

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

form.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User, Item, Type, Image, Category

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('fname', 'lname', 'contact', 'username', 'password')

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'price', 'category_id' )
```

views.py

```
def item_add(request, pk, type_pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.session['username'] == user.pk:

            categories = Category.objects.all()
            #type_submit is the submit button for item_add.html form. 
            #button is either [buy] or [sell]
            type_submit = get_object_or_404(Type, pk=type_pk)
            types = Type.objects.all()

            if request.method == "POST":
                form = ItemForm(request.POST)

                if form.is_valid():
                    item = form.save()
                    item.save()
                    item.objects.create(type_id=type_pk, user_id=pk)
                    return redirect('system.views.user_home', pk=pk)


            else:
                form = ItemForm()

            return render(request, 'system/item_add.html', {'form':form, 'categories': categories,
                                                        'type_submit': type_submit, 'types': types})
    except KeyError:
        return redirect('system.views.user_login')
```

When i click the submit button in my add_item.html nothing happened. No data added in my database. I didn't include the type_id and user_id(they are foreign keys) in my form. Because I don't want to display it in the add_item.html(form). I just want to add it directly after submitting.
Please help me guys. I'm getting crazy with this.

Comment: Is `form.is_valid()` getting `True` ?

Comment: I don't know. There's no error when I run it in my browser. maybe IT's valid

Comment: print something inside` if ` condition, and check.

Comment: Yeah thats y it is not saving to database.So try to valid the form by filling all fields, if not required,add `blank=True` for the coresponding  field.

Comment: I don't know why it is not valid. I checked the form tag in my add_item.html and the forms.py and still I have no idea what's wrong w/ that. Oh man! I'm getting crazy

Comment: type_id = models.ForeignKey('Type', null=True, blank=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Are you displaying form.errors in the template? That'll tell you why it's not valid.

Comment: yes. <ul class="errorlist"><li>category_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a val oice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul> what does this mean?

I can't see the error in my code.
<div class="form-group">
      <label >Category:</label>
      <select name="category_id" required>
        {% for category in categories %}
        <option value="category.pk">{{ category.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div><br>

Comment: Your options are wrong, <option value="category.pk"> change this to <option value="{{category.pk}}">

Answer (score 0):

You have to give;

```
type_id = models.ForeignKey('Type', null=True, blank=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, blank=True)
```

Here blank=True will help for form submittion and null=True helps for saving the data to table

And

```
item.objects.create(type_id=type_pk, user_id=pk)
```

this should be changed to;

```
item.objects.create(type_id=type_submit, user_id=user)
```

Because related fields should be added with objects.

Comment: is it possible to make foreignkeys null?

Comment: i changed it. But the same thing happened. I tried printing "valid" inside the if form.is_valid(). And i confirmed that it's not. I don't know why or how..

Comment: you may not be passing data for 'name', 'description', 'price', 'category_id'.    Try print form.errors, so you will get to know which field you are missing

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>category_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a val
oice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul> what does this mean?

Comment: <option value="category.pk"> change this to <option value="{{category.pk}}">